# How to add string at the beginning of a string, if it is missing or wrong

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to add the string `Sr.` at the beginning of a string if it is missing at all or has missing space or dot.

These strings...

```
Sr. Name
Sr.Name
Name
Sr Name
Sr name
Sr. name
sr.name
```

...should always result in the string `Sr. Name`.

I tried to split the string: `string.split['.']`, but this would not take all cases as shown above. So I tried some regex: `string.replace(/Sr. /, 'Sr. ')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the beginning of the string, optionally match `sr` (case insensitive), followed by an optional `.` and a space, and replace with `'Sr. '` (trailing space included):

```js
`Sr. Name
Sr.Name
Name
Sr Name
Sr name
Sr. name
sr.name`
  .split('\n')
  .forEach((str) => {
    console.log(
      str.replace(/^(?:sr\.? ?)?/i, 'Sr. ')
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in string format like below than you can use regex with `multiline` flag. Instead of split by `\n` and than do some manipulation and than join back by `\n`

```
/^(?:sr\.?\s*)?/igm
```

```js
let op = `Sr. Name
Sr.Name
Name
Sr Name
Sr name
Sr. name
sr.name`.replace(/^(?:sr\.?\s*)?/igm,'Sr. ')

console.log(op)
```