# How to add "55" in the beginning of a string, in case there isn't already?

Tags: sql, metabase, postgresql-13

I have a column with phone numbers that are in string format due to the fact that there might be special characters in the middle. I already cleaned it up, and now I would like to add "55" to the beginning of the string **in case there isn't already**.

My query:

```
SELECT leads.name as "lead's name",
       NULLIF(regexp_replace(leads.phone, '\D','','g'), '') as "lead's phone"

FROM leads

ORDER BY leads.created_at DESC
```

**Observation 1:** It is indifferent to me whether the result is in number format or string format.

**Observation 2:** It is a query on Metabase. I believe to be the most recent version of PostgreSQL.

**Observation 3:** I found a similar question that helps adding the "55" to the beginning of the string, but there is no check to see whether there already is a "55" in the beginning of the string.
[How to add string at the beginning of a string, if it is missing or wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191547/how-to-add-string-at-the-beginning-of-a-string-if-it-is-missing-or-wrong)

Thanks!!

Comment: `UPDATE tablename SET colname = '55' || colname WHERE colname NOT LIKE '55%'` ???

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWillcock! Sorry, but I didn't understand how i would apply that to what I need. On the select, there is "lead's phone", and I would like to add "55" to the beginning of each lead's phone in case there isn't already.

Comment: Same principle but with a case statement. `SELECT CASE WHEN "lead's phone" LIKE '55%' THEN "lead's phone" ELSE '55' || "lead's phone" END as "lead's phone" .. `

Comment: Sorry that i didn't understand at first sight, I got it now. Thanks @JonathanWillcock for taking the time to answer me twice. :)